# Keyboard doesn't open with Tap on TextInputLayout

Tags: java, android, material-design, android-design-library

I have this xml inside a Fragment, which is opened by a NavHostFragment:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/content_title_input"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/top_bottom_space_input"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/top_bottom_space_input">
            <requestFocus/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText>
```

When the Fragment is opened the first time and the user tabs/clicks on the focused TextInputEditText, the Keyboard opens. When my Fragment is opened the second time, the text input field is focused, but when the user taps/clicks on the input field the Keyboard doesn't open anymore. The user needs to tap on another input field to get the Keyboard open.

Is this intended behaviour or am I using something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can show the keyboard manually :

```
imm=(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
```

please reply if solved your problem

Comment: Would work I think, but a little redundant, because the TextInputEditText does call it by itself under normal circumstances. I solved my issue by removing the default focus.